# What do I need for a camera kit for a family photoshoot?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, portrait, children, group-photos, pets

What are some key items to bring for a family (i.e., children, parents, pets) photoshoot?

Comment: What does that mean, a family photoshoot?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't more clear! I meant with children and pets.

Comment: This is rather subjective as it currently reads - you may want to consider re-wording so that it's more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are must have accessories?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-are-must-have-accessories)

Comment: On seeing the title, I was prepared to mark to close as subjective. But the lists given in the answers actually seem pretty useful!

Comment: It would be helpful if it were a bit more specific in the type of location or situation. Is it an outing? Will you have a chance to prepare your shots and pose your family? More context would help getting an accurate answer.

Comment: Is this your family or someone else?  It could make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

1. Patience
2. Camera
3. Lots of Memory
4. Sense of humor
5. Napkins/tissues/paper towels for cleaning up faces (depending on ages of subjects)
6. Brush/comb and maybe detangling solution
7. Patience

Comment: And some more patience...

Comment: Patience.  Definitely patience.

Answer (score 2):

I will add to that:

1. An assistant who can corale people (My wife's family has easily 110 just including the first cousins, so this is necessary for me)
2. A stool to stand on to get everyone in (again, 110 people)
3. A wide lens
4. Keys or jingly/flashy objects to get kids to look at you when everyone else is
5. More patience

Answer (score 1):

Other than patience, I usually brought these items:

1. 2 speed lights & batteries
2. tripod & 1 light stand
3. 1 silver umbrella, 1 white umbrella
4. multi-color reflector
5. CTO gel
6. Camera and 24-70 lens
7. Did I mention patience?